# При создании нового проекта в AppCode выскакивает ошибка

Tags: swift

Xcode not found at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: Вроде по ошибки все ясно.. что ваш Xcode что-то там не нашел в следующей папке.. Может не полная установка, может с ошибкой.. может вы в настройках что-то изменили.

Answer (score 0):

AppCode без корректной установки Xcode не работает.

System requirements

- macOS 10.12 or higher
- Xcode 9.4-10.1
- 4 GB RAM recommended

Взято отсюда
https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/download/